# How to keep the indentation of the content copied to vim from outside with autoindent set?

Tags: vim, auto-indent

I am an average vim user and with an avarage .vimrc containing:

```
set autoindent
```

It's not that bad in general, but when it comes to copying the content from outside, I get the indentation of this piece terribly messed up.
Even worse, if the text contains the comments like "//", they are propagated to the next lines of the copied content even if they originally were not commented.
gg=G doesn't help.

Is there any way to set the autoindent to be disabled on the action of copying something from outside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [described on the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip906). Try adding this to your `.vimrc`:

```
set pastetoggle=<F2>
```

You can set any key - `<F2>` is just an example. Then just press your key to allow pasting, do your copy into Vim, then press the key again to return to normal autoindent behaviour.